# What is the difference between both the sentences?

Tags: difference

Say "I love you"

Say you love me

what's the difference between these two sentences?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is about spoken English, without more context, the most that can be said is that in the first sentence, the speaker is requesting someone to say three words, which may or may not be true - they could have as much significance as "one two three". In the second, the hearer is being asked to make a declaration of love, which, again, may or may not be true.

Comment: Maybe better example sentences are needed, since genuine declarations of love are rarely forthcoming on command or even request.

Comment: And in the second, the declaration of love may take a different form. Rather than responding with a literal "I love you," the response could be "I love you more than anyone else."

Answer (score -2):

Semantically the two sentences have the same meaning

The difference is;
"I love you" in this sentence the lover is the one who said and " you love me" it was said by the one loved. (The receiver of love)

Comment: Note the absence of quotes in the second sentence.